# Setting SNS message attributes via query params when calling the HTTP API

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

So I'm using the SNS HTTP API to publish a message, which follows the following format:

```
POST https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/
    ?Action=Publish
    &Message=%7B%22hello%22:%22World%22%7D
    &TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:1234567890:sns-topic-name
    &Subject=some-subject
```

The reason I can't use their standard API with a request body is because API Gateway -> SNS integration does not seem to support it or will actually require a huge amount of request rewriting, which I am not sure is even possible without putting a Lambda in between. And I can't put in a lambda in between because there is a strict requirement of HA-only services for this particular pipeline.

The integration above works perfect, no issues. Now the problem is, I want to send message attributes as well, but I am able to find next to no documentation on how to encode them in query strings when calling the HTTP endpoint. I've tried the following:

```
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.Name=message-key
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.Value=message-value
```

```
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.Name=message-key
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.DataType=String
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.Value=message-value
```

```
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.Name=message-key
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.DataType=String
   &MessageAttribute.entry.1.StringValue=message-value
```

When I first tried it with `entry.0` I got an error "0 is an invalid index" - so I tried it with `1`. The error I get now is always "Unexpected end of complex structure", which even upon searching didn't land me anywhere.

I tried using `aws cli` with `--debug` and it looks like they are using POST request with a SNS-specific body, which as I mentioned above, is not really an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? It's driving me up the wall... As far as I can tell it should be `MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType=String` and `MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue=message-value`. Plural.

Comment: WHOOT! I had a problem in the name of the param. Make SURE it's `MessageAttributes`, and that you have `.Value` in the two value parts.

Comment: A gist with my API DefinitionBody which includes request rewriting to SNS (without a lambda). https://gist.github.com/datashaman/054f128968311cc7c4a20c51f7bd21ee

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to post a string message attribute for SNS:

```
&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name=message-key
&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType=String
&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue=message-value
```

Note especially that it is a *plural* `MessageAttributes`, the word `entry`, and also `Value`.